# Jquery ajax url not getting called on dropdown change?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call jquery ajax on dropdown change function.But on changing dropdown nothing seems to happen. The code is written below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#locationList").change(function () {
             FillCashSafe();
         })

     });
 function FillCashSafe() {
         var locationNo = document.getElementById('<%=locationList.ClientID%>').value;             
         alert(locationNo);//**alert is working properly**
         $.ajax({                 
             type: "POST",               
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes") %>',
             data: "{}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {                        
                     $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeDisplaySerialNo));
                 });
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
             }
         });
     }
```

Code behind is written below

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static Cashsafe[] GetCashsafes(string Location)
    {
        Decimal userId = (Decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId;
        List<Cashsafe> cashsafes = DropDown.getCashSafeListLocationwise(userId, Convert.ToInt32(Location));
        return cashsafes.ToArray();
    }
```

Markup is as follows

```
<div class="controls">
   <select class="chzn-select" data-rel="chosen" id="locationList" name="Location"  runat="server">
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your WebMethod is called or not?

Comment: I Mean that the Method GetCashsafes from your codebehind is called or not?

Comment: yes. which is given above

Comment: Did you get any error message or your dropdown filled with "Select one"

Comment: yes i put an `alert("Error")` inside error function and the alert shows.

Comment: Yes can you mention which error is occur? you can alert('result') in error section.

Comment: Strange..I am getting error as [object Object].Any Idea..

Comment: It means that it will give you object so need to debug and then need to be check that your Code behind method is return json value. and then you write in error section that alert("json.parse(result)");

Comment: I've written the code-behind above. I'm returning array there.How can i return json value there.

Comment: Check this link. http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 0):

Put httppost attribute on server method and try again

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
    public static Cashsafe[] GetCashsafes(string Location)
    {
        Decimal userId = (Decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId;
        List<Cashsafe> cashsafes = DropDown.getCashSafeListLocationwise(userId, Convert.ToInt32(Location));
        return cashsafes.ToArray();
    }
```

and aloso pass location as shown below

```
$.ajax({                 
             type: "POST",               
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes") %>',
             data: "{'Location' : locationNo}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {                        
                     $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeDisplaySerialNo));
                 });
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
             }
         });
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but nothing seems to happen.:(